# Letras "ã õ ũ ẽ" en español antiguo

Tags: pronunciación, abreviaturas, letras, español-medieval

Hace unas semanas me encontré con un texto antiguo donde `ã õ ũ ẽ` sustituían a las silabas  `an on un en`. Por ejemplo *"ẽtõces"* en lugar de *"entonces"*.

No pude encontrar otra vez ese texto.

Quisiera saber si esas representaciones reflejaban la fonética de la palabra. Es decir si esas vocales eran nasales, o si solo se trataba de una forma de economizar la escritura.

Eso me recuerda a la teoría del origen de la `ñ`, donde supuestamente es la abreviatura de `nn`, y la virgulilla representaría una n pequeña sobre otra n. Ello en palabras como `anno` y `año`, `hispannia` y `españa`. Cuya explicacion aplicaria

```
ã → an
õ → on
ũ → un
ẽ → en
```

Aquí les dejo el [enlace](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?N.-) del origen de la Ñ para que lo lean si lo desean. Donde por cierto también mencionan las vocales con `~` sobre ellas. Pero no dice si era solo cuestión escrita o también fonética.

Comment: En el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, accesible desde el NTTLE de la web de la RAE, muchas definiciones usan las grafías que comentas en tu pregunta.

Comment: En los incunables, el tilde, al aplicarse sobre letras altas como *b d f h l ſ t*, con gran frecuencia salió más como un cuerno o apóstrofe.  *gl’a* significaba *gloria*, pero escrito a mano, sería *gla* con un tilde grande sobre toda la palabra.  Pero era solo una abreviatura

Answer (score 7):

Antiguamente la `~` se utilizaba para marcar abreviaturas en el texto, particularmente las `m` y `n`. Recuerda que el papel y el pergamino eran bastante caros, así que las abreviaturas ahorraban dinero.

Otras abreviatura similares son la `q̃` por `que`, la `ö` por `oe` en alemán, o la `ø` por `oe` en sueco...

De hecho en castellano la `ñ` en ocasiones se escribía como `nn` (otras veces `ny` o `nh` o `gn`) que evolucionó de forma natural a `ñ`.

En portugués, sin embargo la `n` a final de sílaba tendió a perderse y a nasalizar la vocal previa, y la `~` se convirtió en una marca diacrítica.

Pero estoy divagando... Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> Quisiera saber si esas representaciones reflejaban la fonética de la palabra. Es decir si esas vocales eran nasales, o si solo se trataba de una forma de economizar la escritura.

No indica fonética, son solo abreviaturas.