# When did the medieval contractions that used the 'tilde' fall out of use?

Tags: historia, abreviaturas

[We already know](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18767/12637) that Old Spanish used a lot of contractions just to save space in writings. In the manuscripts for *El cantar de mio Cid* we can see *nõ* for *non*, *cõ* for *con* and *q̃* for *que*. This practice was extended at least until the 17th century. For instance, we can see this in the original edition of *Quixote* from 1605:

[image: Quixote]

And this in the Covarrubias' dictionary from 1611:

[image: Covarrubias]

But when did these contractions fall out of use? Was it just that they were no more needed as paper costs decreased? Or did the RAE have to intervene to stop the contractions?

Comment: Note: these abbreviations have their basis in Latin scribal shorthand, and were also used in [French and Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Abbreviation) texts up until a similar point in time (17th C). I am pretty certain that they fell out of use purely due to decreased cost of printing material making them unnecessary. If you look at your own examples, you see many words with "vowel + n", and "que" appearing in the same sentence as "q̃".

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7vreUPCl9c), *How Spanish got its ñ*, by NativLang might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El articulo [*Un esbozo histórico de las formas abreviadas
españolas con índices de continuidad y de suavidad*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/publicaciones_centros/PDF/tokio_2015/06_ueda.pdf) describe el uso y la frecuencia de los distintos tipos de abreviaturas en bastante detalla. Dice que se decayó en desuso en el siglo XVII, al mismo tiempo que los de francés y portugués (los unicos vestigios ya siendo la [Ñ](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18868/cu%C3%A1ndo-se-incorpor%C3%B3-la-%C3%91-al-abecedario-como-letra-con-entidad-propia) en castellano, y los [vocales nasales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18767/letras-%C3%A3-%C3%B5-%C5%A9-%E1%BA%BD-en-espa%C3%B1ol-antiguo) en portugués):

> **En el siglo XVII decae el uso de la abreviación**, como notamos en la obra maestra cervantina, donde las palabras marcadas con línea no están abreviadas a la
>   manera de lo que ocurría en los casos citados en las obras de siglos anteriores...
>
> [image]
>
> Notamos que hay más proporción de letras abreviadas en los siglos xiii y xiv,
>   menos en los siglos xv y xvi, aún más reducida en el siglo xvii y prácticamente nula
>   en los siglos xviii y xix.

En particular, aquí son los dados sobre q̃ ("que"):

> #### 5.2 q<ue>
>
> La frecuencia de la abreviación de q<ue> es alta y se prolonga hasta el siglo
>   XVII. Son destacables el descenso total en el Fuero de Alcalá (s. XIII) y las subidas
>   grandes en General Estoria (s. XIII) y Conde Lucanor (s. XIV-XV). También hay que
>   notar su uso frecuente en Diálogo de la lengua (s. XVI).
>
> [image]